# Exchange Online - Route email to different address depending on sender initials

Tags: mail-forwarding, exchangeonline

So our HR department is tiny, and gets an enormous amount of email from our agency at large. They'd like us to forward email to different  members of their team, based on the alphabetical order of the sender name.

We've figured out we can use regex to parse the email subject, but I'm concerned that doesn't necessarily get us there. Can we just pull the initials from the sender's email address set a forwarding rule as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transport rules to gain what you want.

You configure recipient, sender options (use "match" option to get REGEXP working) and action you want to do.

I recommend to create a highly precise rule, so you could be sure that no unwanted messages will be processed by your rule.

If you want to monitor, you can configure additional action "generate incident and send it to..." and choose the applying mode for the rule "test with policy tips"

Here's an example:
[transport rule example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCc8Y.png)

Comment: That's the approach we settled on as well. The regex is a nice touch from Microsoft.